# SQLint showing a syntax error, yet batch file is run correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm using Sublime Text with the [SublimeLinter-contrib-sqlint](https://github.com/trezona-lecomte/SublimeLinter-contrib-sqlint) plugin and following the tutorial examples at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/examples.html, one of which contains the following:

```
CREATE TABLE shop (
    article INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,
    dealer  CHAR(20)                 DEFAULT ''     NOT NULL,
    price   DOUBLE(16,2)             DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(article, dealer));
INSERT INTO shop VALUES
    (1,'A',3.45),(1,'B',3.99),(2,'A',10.99),(3,'B',1.45),
    (3,'C',1.69),(3,'D',1.25),(4,'D',19.95);
```

In Sublime Text with the linter enabled, I see a syntax error:

[image]

If I hover over it, it just says "ERROR: Syntax error near "("". However, it seems to run fine as batch input:

```
mysql> source shop.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

Any idea what might be causing this 'false positive' syntax error?

Comment: `int` doesn't usually take a length, but MySQL does allow it.  So, it is MySQL-specific thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue looks like it's caused by the underlying linting tool not using the correct dialect of SQL, which makes it think that the SQL you're using is not valid even though (for MySQL) it is.

Looking a bit deeper, the [SublimeLinter-contrib-sqlint](https://github.com/trezona-lecomte/SublimeLinter-contrib-sqlint) package says that it uses [sqlint](https://github.com/purcell/sqlint) to do the linting, and the README in that repository includes this:

> At this stage, SQLint checks SQL against the ANSI syntax, and uses the PostgreSQL SQL parser to achieve this. In time, we hope to add support for non-standard SQL variants (e.g. MySQL). Contributions are welcome.

As such it seems like at the moment the tool isn't capable of linting SQL files that use non-ANSI/PostgreSQL flavoured SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that a string is a valid default value for an INT.